# Target runtime WebSphere Application Server traditional V9.0 is not defined

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

i'm using Eclipse neon 3, when i import a project which used Description     WebSphere Application Server traditional V9.0 as run time environment, it shown an error announced that

> Target runtime WebSphere Application Server traditional V9.0 is not defined

I'm already install and run  WebSphere Application Server, how can i add it into eclipse as runtime environment, i'm newbie to WAS

Answer (score 2):

From the IBM docs:

> In the workbench, select Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime
>   Environments.  Click Add.  Select WebSphere Application Server
>   traditional Version, and then click Next. Specify the installation
>   directory.  The JRE for the runtime environment: list is
>   automatically displayed.The list contains the IBM SDKs including the
>   default IBM SDK. For WebSphere Application Server traditional V8.5,
>   the default IBM SDK is Version 6.